# Adding Lists and Counting Y and X Objects Counts Both Objects In Both Categories

Tags: python, counting

```
x =  object
y = object

x_list = [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
y_list= [y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y]
big_list = y_list + x_list
print("x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_list))
print("y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list))
print("big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list))

if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Bruv")
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("A'ight")
else:
    print("nah")
```

Whenever I run this, it says "Blig_list contains 20 items," and therefore it prints "nah".

How do I fix this?

Comment: In this code, `x` and `y` are different names for the same thing.

Comment: If you want a unique sentinel object, you probably want to *call* `object()` and use the instance. Just naming `object` means that both `x` and `y` are references to the type, which is not what you want.

Comment: You haven't *called* an object function; you have set both `x` and `y` to the `object` class.  Then you built two lists with ten references to that class, and a `big_list` with 20 references.  We can't tell you how to "fix" this, because you haven't described what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your big_list with objects contains 20 equal objects. You can check it with x == y, it returns True.
Try this x and y:

```
x = 'a'
y = 'b'
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by this? Will I have to change my lists aswell?

Comment: I mean that you have equal objects within both lists.
Can you please share what type of objects you intend to have within x_list and y_list?

Comment: It is from a beginner's course I am taking online.

Some of the code doesn't work on Pycharm, but it works on "IPython shell".

I don't intend to actually use this in any way, just to understand what the object function does.

Comment: Perhaps, you can then try replacing `object` with `object()`. Then this will initiate different instances for x_list and y_list. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, but I got this error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mandem/PycharmProjects/untitled/Pranks/Lib/site-packages/Ada.py", line 1, in <module>
    object(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined